# FileOutputStream error exception

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

Hi i get a error in save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
i do not what to do, is media app, this function assumes that the application should save the song as a ringtone

```
 public boolean saveas(int type, int position) {
    Log.i("ramiro", "entro saveas");
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(
            s1[position]);
    int size = 0;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("ramiro", "error1 try");
        return false;
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/media/audio/ringtones/";

    String filename = title[position];
    Log.i("ramiro", "filename: " + filename);

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename); //error
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        Log.i("ramiro", "paso flush");
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("ramiro", "try2 filenotfoundexception");
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("ramiro", "try2 ioexception");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `i do not what to do`, `is media app`, `this function assumes` ... could you please make your mind clear?

Comment: What is the exact exception?

Comment: Never catch an exception without printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
FileOutputStream save;
```

with

```
FileOutputStream save = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are your issues:

- You have a buffer size of 0, how should that work?
- Even if you raise your buffer size, you are only reading one buffer. You need a loop.

Moreover, if your code crashes where you have added the //error comment:

- Make sure title is not null
- Make sure you have the permission to write on external storage